# Identify moss features from GUID

Tags: 2007, feature-activation

We are using a site definition and it has 3 feature dependencies that we are struggling to identify:

```
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="7EDD3C9C-8AC6-4ab5-A209-30B5DC422464" />
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="63FDC6AC-DBB4-4247-B46E-A091AEFC866F" />
<ActivationDependency FeatureId="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416" />
```

Can anyone identify what these features or give me an idea as to how to identify them?

I think they are out of the box moss features but they are not installed on the farm currently.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 6):

What i usually do is very lo-tech: i use NotePad++ or UltraSeek's "Search In Files" functionality to search for the GUID in question in the FEATURES folder in the 12 hive.

That gives me both where it is defined and where it is used.

Answer (score 4):

If you have SP2 installed in your environment you could run the preupgradecheck via STSADM e.g. STSADM -o preupgradecheck

This will generate a report for you which among other things will list all the features in your environment and give you the feature name and GUID.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789638.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Anders' approach. If the features still can't be found then there are tools by Stefan Gossner that will help you clean them up:

- [WssAnalyzeFeatures](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WssAnalyzeFeatures): verifies that the feature definition files for all installed features are present on the file system
- [WssRemoveFeatureFromSite](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WssRemoveFeatureFrom): removes the feature from the site or site collection completely if stsadm -o deactivatefeature does not work

Answer (score 2):

I ended up running one sp-getfeatureid | Format-Table DisplayName per missing feature. I wrote up my solution put it online with some [screenshots from my experience](http://tomresing.com/2011/03/23/test-spcontentdb-plus-get-spfeature-plus-excel-for-upgrading-help/) trying to do the same. The post also shows why enumsolutions doesn't work.

I've also found Powershell like below can help:

`get-childitem -filter *.xml . -recurse | Select-String -pattern "aebe3546-9675-458d-b818-a3a412ad1546"|format-list filename, path`

Comment: +1 for the PowerShell approach. I used this technique once for finding all FeatureStapplings. I used the Xml features of PowerShell, but the idea is the same

Comment: Can you update your link @tom?

Comment: Updated. My latest hosting move broke my redirect from the SharePoint post id to the pretty name which Sp community edition blog and Wordpress use. Readable url to that post is http://tomresing.com/2011/03/23/test-spcontentdb-plus-get-spfeature-plus-excel-for-upgrading-help/ Also, you can browse my entire archives by date. This post was made the same day as the answer and can be found in the March 2011 archive at http://tomresing.com/2011/03/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to query the Configuration database:

```
SELECT Properties FROM MOSS_CONFIG_DB_NAME.[dbo].[Objects] where id='GUID'
```

The XML in the properties column is XML that should have a path to the feature.xml for more information. The content alone tells you the name.

Comment: If there is another way, querying the database directly is always discouraged. It's not documented. And there is no guarantee of schema or data meaning stability between patch levels if it is interpreted correctly in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

In SharePoint 2007 you can use the stsadm.exe enumsolutions command which will spit out not only their names, but also what scope they are set for and whether they are deployed.

In SharePoint 2010 'there's a Powershell cmdlet for that'.

Comment: enumsolutions outputs solution ids not feature ids