# SP 2007 Upgraded to SP 2010 . "Upgraded Completed with errors .Review log files "

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Respected All,
             I need to upgrade one of the SP 2007 Content Db to SP 2010.The below image tells i.e I have attached the Content DB of SP 2007 to SP 2010 Web Application ,In addition to i.e it shows me information as " Upgraded Completed with errors .Review log files " .I open the Site after Upgration it is running fine ,But there is no Lists,Document Libraries,Calenders in the site .Please see the  log files from the below link  and help me in solving this problem
http://sdrv.ms/NV2Q3q 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, the issue appears to be related to features that are not available in the new farm.

Here's one of the lines from the log:

> Found a missing feature Id = [959b81c0-71bd-4606-ac5b-2caf93cc1c00]
>
> The feature with Id 959b81c0-71bd-4606-ac5b-2caf93cc1c00 is referenced in the database [MedicationM2005DB], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

Firstly identify the feature with the Guid in the MOSS farm.  Then determine if you can/want to upgrade to a sp2010 version of it.

This SharePoint SE question explains how to find a feature by GUID: [Identify moss features from GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/identify-moss-features-from-guid)